# Detect sub-image in low-resolution image collection (old documents scans)

Tags: image, ocr

My question is quite simple. I have a huge collection of low-quality scans of old documents, namely old texts written in Chinese characters. I would like to detect all images containing a word (composed of Kanji characters, e.g. 城).

I have tried using OCR (with Tesseract), even with a restricted white list, but it fails to identify the given characters when present, certainly because the documents are old and the scanning was done at a low resolution, consequently the characters are blurred and even sometimes seem to lack strokes (see example below).

[Excerpt of a scanned document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vlzp.png)

I am therefore thinking to resort to other image analysis techniques and would appreciate your advice. (Please note that I prefer getting false positives better than false negatives here.)

Thank you very much for your time and consideration.

---

Additional documents (in response to Mark's request):

[Excerpt of First Document containing 議員](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X5JT.png)

[Excerpt of Second Document containing 議員](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOMTq.png)

[Reference image for 議員 (pronounced "giin")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kExuC.png)

Comment: Interesting project - can you provide a second sample document and scans of a couple of individual *"perfect"* characters that exist in them? I think OCR is probably the wrong approach - I would probably just look at the shapes and maybe do some kind of correlation.

Comment: Hi Tim and Mark, and thank you for your feedback. I also think that OCR is the wrong approach in this case, but don't know much about image analysis techniques. @MarkSetchell: I have updated my question with two excerpts of documents mentioning at multiple places the kanjis "議員", and I also included a screenshot of these kanjis written with different fonts in Libreoffice Writer (as "perfect" examples).

Comment: No idea anybody? I was not expecting this issue to be that challenging.